# Comparing current and historic data, which comes first?

Tags: info-visualisation, data-tables, comparison

I'm building an interface to report on our accessibility testing, which would compare the current state (ie the most recent set of testing) with a past state (by selected date), but I'm not sure which to show first, the way things are now or the way they were then.

Showing the current state first makes sense to me - not least because it means that the first thing the user sees is the value that looks best for us - but others have suggested that displaying the past state first as it shows the progression, and that's what would generally be expected if more than two values were being displayed.

This is (possibly) complicated by the fact that I want to show a pair of pie charts with a table beneath them to contain some breakdowns. Clearly, the pie charts should reflect the order in the table (I'm not an animal), but what is the best order?

This is a quick version of what I'm thinking[image: screenshot of current design, showing pie charts of the current state on the left and the comparison (past) state on the right, with a table breaking down tests into Pass, Fail, Incomplete and Not Applicable, with the Pass and Fail results displaying both the current figures and the figures for the comparison state]

Comment: Nothing to do with the actual question, but the use of "current" by itself assumes that the only time anyone will look at this information will be now.  Anyone looking at a copy of it in the future will be out of luck, because "current" will actually mean "*Sometime between January 2023 and now, but we're not telling you when!*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you have it now is correct. On the one hand, because it's the most common pattern. On the other hand, because you have the date dropdown on the right, so I'd expect the graph close to that dropdown belongs to that element.

Other than that, I think you could try bar graphs since you have a lot of straight lines the circles look a bit weird (or enclose them within a container with a border). But this is just a personal opinion, the important part is that your current wireframe is correct

**EDIT:**

Couldn't find a pie chart, but here are different data visualization examples where you will see how current data comes first, and older data follows. Please note that we are discussing your specific case, wireframe, and similar cases where context is needed to compare with older data.

Additionally, this aligns with the **EDIT:
Couldn't find a pie chart, but here are different data visualization examples where you will see how current data comes first, and older data follows. Please note that we are discussing your specific case, wireframe, and similar cases where context is needed to compare with older data.

Additionally, this aligns with the [**Gestalt Law of Proximity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_grouping). Having a dropdown with older data, followed by a graph with newer data would cause a significant cognitive load. Essentially, you would be presenting contradictory information to your users simultaneously.

In other cases, you may need to prioritize displaying older data first (for example, when showcasing a baseline and its evolution over time, or hwen you use timelines). However, in this situation, you would require a different layout and probably a different type of graph.

**Google Analytics** shows the option to show sets of data by date. Today comes first, then older data comes afterwards. I used GA3 for the first capture and GA4 for rteh second because they have somehow similar examples, but this is the same logic they use for all their products: in GA4 you see today and 7 days first, older data comes later. In Calendar you start today, you need to perform a secondary action to see previous dates.

[image]
[image]

**RankRanger** compares data from today to a date in the past. Doing it otherwise would make no sense (RankRanger uses Google Analytics as well)
[image]

Also, think on a Gantt chart: you start with today, then you have data in teh future and in teh past, but you need to know  what data do you have now, the past is information you need, but your current status isn't the same anymore.

Comment: Do you have any references for it being the most common pattern? The only things I've been able to find refer to product comparisons and I can't seem to find a way to search for data state comparisons

Answer (score 0):

Why not show both in one graph, I personally really like this graph on Google's [CrUX Dashboard](https://lookerstudio.google.com/reporting/bbc5698d-57bb-4969-9e07-68810b9fa348/page/TvuS?params=%7B%22origin%22:%22https:%2F%2Fgoogle.com%22%7D):

[image: redesign of google's crux dashboard to fit answer]

I've augmented it show how it could represent your data, also the values don't have to add up to 100%, but for comparison's sake I think it's the best move, since I'm assuming it's more important to compare performance over a month rather than over a quarter/year.

Colours can be swapped out to yours if you like btw.

But personally, my favourite has to be the good old line graph. Especially if you want to compare over a longer time period. You can't go wrong with it. You can see below how well it allows you to see how information correlates over time:

[image: a multiline line graph]